# "This is not a supported method of installing the operating system" when reinstalling OS X after formatting

Tags: macos, install

After formatting my MacBook, when I reinstall OS X it doesn't come. When I skip that I can't choose startup disk because nothing shows up.

> This is not a supported method of installing the operating system.
>   Please run Install OS X Mavericks.app that you downloaded from the App Store.

[image: Photo of above error message]

Comment: did you try command + r   to boot in recovery mode?  Command (⌘) + Option (⌥) + R for internet recovery, if you machine support it. What is the model of this mac?

Comment: Be more specific, what *EXACT METHOD* did you use to reinstall macOS?